# How to take the first two letters of a variable in python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset like below:

```
data
id    message
 1    ffjffjf
 2    ddjbgg
 3    vvnvvv
 4    eevvff
 5    ggvfgg
```

Expected output:

```
data
id    message  splitmessage
 1    ffjffjf    ff
 2    ddjbgg     dd
 3    vvnvvv     vv
 4    eevvff     ee
 5    ggvfgg     gg
```

I am very new to Python. So how can I take 1st two letters from each row in `splitmessage` variable.

my data exactly looks like below image
[image: need to split that]
so from the image i want only hour and min's which are 12 to 16 elements in each row of vfreceiveddate variable.

Comment: Show your current code. Also, you do want to do your basic research based on the terms "python substring"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a substring.

```
mystr = str(id1)
splitmessage = mystr[:2]
```

Method we are using is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) in python, works for more than strings.

In next example 'message' and 'splitmessage' are [lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm).

```
message = ['ffjffjf', 'ddjbgg']
splitmessage = []
for myString in message:
    splitmessage.append(myString[:2])
print splitmessage
```

Comment: in mystr = str(id1)  what do you mean by id1

Comment: I mean the message at id 1.

Comment: it is working only for the 1st one,     mystr = str(data['message'])    splitmessage = mystr[:2] 
 but how can i do that for whole variable

Comment: ```myString``` as the name for variable violates PEP-0008!

Comment: Iterating the whole dataset and appending the new string to splitmessage.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, @Igor

Answer (score 1):

```
dataset = [
    { "id": 1, "message": "ffjffjf" },
    { "id": 2, "message": "ddjbgg" },
    { "id": 3, "message": "vvnvvv" },
    { "id": 4, "message": "eevvff" },
    { "id": 5, "message": "ggvfgg" }
]

for d in dataset:
    d["splitmessage"] = d["message"][:2]
```

Comment: my data type is pandas.core.series.series so how can i do that at that point

Comment: I asked exactly for output of ```print``` command, which will help me to determine what data structure is used to represent the date you have to deal with.

Comment: By the way, if you have to extract some parts of date/time representation, it's probable not the best idea to manipulate strings. You can work with ```datetime``` objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for the entire table, I would do it like this:

```
dataset = [id1, id2, id3 ... ]
for id in dataset:
   splitid = id[:2]
```